# If $f:X \to Y $ is continuous then $f^{-1}(\emptyset)= \emptyset?$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

If $f:X \to Y $ is continuous then $f^{-1}(\emptyset)= \emptyset?$ (I know the inverse of a closed set of a continuous function is closed, but is this a must?)

And does the following apply to all functions or continuous ones:

1.)$f(A \cup B)=f(A) \cup f(B)$

2.)$f(A \cap B)=f(A) \cap f(B)$

Comment: How about now? I meant empty set there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Continuity has nothing to do with either.

In the first case, no assumptions are needed except that $f$ be a mapping. If $f^{-1}(\varnothing) \neq \varnothing$, then there's $x \in f^{-1}(\varnothing)$ and this means that $f(x) \in \varnothing$ which is impossible.

In the second case, also only $f$ being a mapping is required for $1)$. However, for $2)$, we need injectivity.

**Edit:**

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a mapping. Then:

$f^{-1}(A \cap B) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$

Where for any $M \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(M) := \{x \in X, f(x) \in M \}$.

Proof: For the first inclusion, let $x \in f^{-1}(A \cap B)$, then $f(x) \in A \cap B$, so $f(x) \in A$ and $f(x) \in B$, so that $x \in f^{-1}(A)$ and $x \in f^{-1}(B)$, i.e. $x \in f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$. Now let $x \in f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$, then $x \in f^{-1}(A)$ and $x \in f^{-1}(B)$, so $f(x) \in A$ and $f(x) \in B$, so that $f(x) \in A \cap B$, thus $x \in f^{-1}(A \cap B)$.

Comment: My book directly used the secong sub case on a inverse of a continuous map

Comment: @Leb Can you conclude that the inverse of a function with an inverse is necessarily injective?

Comment: It must be ? this was used as a inverse mapping more than a function per say

Comment: @LebronJames: then that's a very different thing. What you stated works with the inverse mapping regardless of the nature of the mapping itself.

Comment: what are your thoughts on that ?

Comment: Try to prove that $f^{-1}(A \cap B) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$. If you got stuck, I'll edit my answer to prove it.

Comment: I did, that's why I ask. :)

Comment: @LebronJames: check the edit.

Comment: Side note, is "inverse mapping" really common terminology for the preimage? The distinction between an inverse function, and the preimage, is often a source of confusion, and that terminology certainly doesn't help...

Comment: Lebron you're welcome. @pjs36: you're right. I should have been more careful with terminologies. I'll edit my answer to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

Of course $f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$, there is no element which has an image in the empty set, hence the set of elements whose image is in the empty set is empty.

We have $f(A)\cup f(B)=f(A\cup B)$ for every function.

We have $f(A)\cap f(B)=f(A\cap B)$ if and only if $f$ is injective (otherwise suppose $f(a)=f(b)$ with $a\neq b$. Then $f(\{a\})\cup f(\{b\}$ is not empty while $f(\{a\}\cap\{b\})$ is. Hence all we have to know is whether there exist continuous functions that are not injective. The constant functions are examples of non-injective continuous functions.

---

To summarize, all of your questions can be understood just by knowing results about functions in general, the matter of continuity is mostly superficial in this case.